# What is the difference between System.out.printf and System.out.format specifically in Blue Java?

Tags: java, printf, difference, println, system.out

I've been watching a tutorial in Java and suddenly saw that the teacher is using System.out.format in the same way of using System.out.printf and is fetching the same results. So I'm a bit confused between the two.

Comment: If by "Blue Java" you mean "BlueJ" then it does not matter, BlueJ is just an IDE for editing and compiling/running Java code; the IDE you use to write the code will not change what the code does. If you mean something else, then please clarify, as there does not seem to be any programming tool named "Blue Java"; especially when talking about programming, you need to use correct terminology for people to know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look at the documentation of `printf` reveils:

*An invocation of this method of the form out.printf(format, args)

behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation

`out.format(format, args)`*

Jumping into the `printf` method we see:

```
return format(format, args);
```

So printf is just another interface to call `format()`